# Total path lengths in MST in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

Good day to all.

I have an adjacency matrix of minimum spanning tree (MST) of size (1200x1200) and I wish to find the total path lengths among nodes in matrix form.

For example, if I have an adjacency matrix of size (4x4) as follows,
[image]
then the total path length matrix is showed.

The total path lengths among node 1 and node 4 is 3, the number of edges from node 1 to node 4 or vice-versa.

For my case, I tried to use Dijkstra's algorithm for finding the total path lengths among the nodes. If I set the starting and target nodes, I need to do (1200*1199)/2 times calculation. So, I tried to use loop function to solve the calculation problem. But, the process is already run for two days still the desired result is not come out...

I would like to ask: Is there any efficient algorithm for finding the total path lengths in large MST?

Thank you.

Comment: Please define "total path lengths". With a diagram, if possible.

Comment: @beaker I edited the post with adding an example. Tq

Comment: The obvious answer is Floyd-Warshall, but that's still `O(V^3)`. I'm pretty sure that we can take advantage of the MST structure and get that down to `O(V^2)` doing something like a depth-first traversal. I'll add the [tag:algorithm] tag to hopefully get the right people looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Updated code to account for the distance between children of the same parent (which should always be 2).

This seems to work. I went with a breadth-first traversal rather than depth-first so as to limit the number of nodes on the stack.

From the current Parent node (we start with node 1) we find the distance from the children C of P to each of the previously visited nodes. This is simply the distance from those nodes to P, plus the distance from P to C, or 1.

We then add the children to the stack and mark P as visited by setting row P and column P in the adjacency matrix to 0's. Continue until all nodes have been visited (the stack is empty).

```
A = [0 1 0 0;          %// Adjacency matrix
     1 0 1 0;
     0 1 0 1;
     0 0 1 0]

D = zeros(size(A));    %// Distance matrix

S = [1];               %// The stack initially contains Node 1

while numel(S) > 0
   P = S(end);         %// Pop the top element from the stack
   S = S(1:end-1);
   C = find(A(P,:));   %// Get all children of P
   for child = 1:numel(C)
      %// Distance to child = distance to parent + 1
      %// for non-zero distances only
      D(C(child),:) = D(P,:)+(D(P,:)>0);
      %// Distance to child from parent is 1
      D(C(child),P) = 1;
      S(end+1) = C(child);   %// Add child to stack
      %// This doesn't seem like the most elegant solution
      %// but it should work.
      if child > 1           %// Update distance to previous siblings
         for sib = 1:child-1
            D(C(child),C(sib)) = 2;
         end
      end
   end
   A(P,:) = 0;         %// Delete parent from adjacency matrix
   A(:,P) = 0;
end

D =  D + D.'           %// We've only found D(s,t)... add D(t,s)
```

The output for the example matrix is:

```
A =

   0   1   0   0
   1   0   1   0
   0   1   0   1
   0   0   1   0

D =

   0   1   2   3
   1   0   1   2
   2   1   0   1
   3   2   1   0
```

Comment: As you said that Floyd-Warshall can be used to find all pairs shortest path, I found this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25776-vectorized-floyd-warshall

Comment: Floyd-Warshall is `O(V^3)` whereas the code I've given is `O(V^2)`. I'm not sure how much difference the optimization on the vectorized version will make, so you might try both on smaller problems and see which works better for you.